# ubuntu 16.04 confuse wireless card with ethernet

Tags: wireless, 16.04

Dears,
I just upgraded my XPS 13 to ubuntu 16.04
Now when i start my internal wireless adapter is recognized as a ethernet card instead of wireless card.

If I start the computer with my Dell DA200 connected, it does recognize then the adapter as ethernet and the internal adapter is properly recognized as wifi and works.

When it works, lspci yields
3a:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 08)

Answer (score 0):

I thin you have this bug appearing on your system. Please read the description. It's affecting many Ubuntu users:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/network-manager/+bug/1574347

Cheers

Comment: This looks like a link only answer ...